# Does the US map of AnyMap have DC and Puerto Rico

Tags: anychart

I have explored the gallery of AnyMap. It seems that the current US map doesn't support Washington D.C. and Puerto Rico. I was wondering if there is anyway to add these two "states" to this map? If not, what is the best way to represent data of these two? For example, adding two legends?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as Anychart uses Geo JSON standard for GeoData, you can use any free or paid source of geo data.
For example, I have found a highcharts map and wrote a simple converter for anychart library.

```
chart.geoData(Convertor.convert(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-all-territories']));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwhn5ce2/